# Dictionary in a Dictionary, how to remove and aggregate all the data

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the below dictionary and want to put all the fruit into a new dictionary ie the output would be

```
{"Apples":1, "Banana":1, "Pear":1, "Orange":2}.
```

I keep stumbling at the point where Andy has a dictionary in a dictionary which I cannot figure out how to deal with.

```
{
    "Martin":{"Apples":1},
    "Andy":{"Dad":{"Banana":1}},
    "Lucy":{"Pear":1,"Orange":2}
}
```

Any advice please.

Comment: Why do you have inconsistent data like this in the first place?

Comment: Are these the only possible layouts, or can there be arbitrary levels of nesting? In the latter case, use a recursive function that recurses when the value is a dictionary rather than an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's built in [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check what is the type of your value, and [recursive calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) to process the value as the flat data:

```
data = {
    "Martin":{"Apples":1},
    "Andy":{"Dad":{"Banana":1}},
    "Lucy":{"Pear":1,"Orange":2}
}

fruits = {}
def add_fruits(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            # it's a dict go one more level
            add_fruits(value)
        else: # it's a fruit
            fruits[key] += value 
add_fruits(data)
print(fruits)
```

Which gives the following:

```
{'Apples': 1, 'Banana': 1, 'Pear': 1, 'Orange': 2}
```